# How to get the item at the specific position in a combo box?

Tags: forms, vba, combobox

I need to get the item that is at a specific position in a combo box.

This is what I'm trying:

```
Private Sub PrintItems(Combo As ComboBox)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Combo.ListCount
        Debug.Print Combo(i) ' Combo(i) is pseudo-code to get the item
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `List` collection. It's zero-based, so the 3rd item in the combobox would be index `2` and you should iterate from `0` to `ListCount - 1`:

```
For i = 0 To Combo.ListCount - 1
    Debug.Print Combo.List(i)
Next
```